# Fatal Error while installing mysql-advanced 5.7.19 - Solaris 11 Sparc 64 bit

Tags: mysql

I tried to install mysql advanced 5.7.19 to non-default location onto Solaris SPARC 64bit
Non-default location: `/opt/app/mysql`

But face the following error:
**During pkgadd:** ld.so.1: mysqld: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by file bin/mysqld)

**During mysql_install_db**: ld.so.1: mysql_install_db: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by file mysql_install_db)

Below are my steps:

```
# working directory: /export/home/admin
root@host:/export/home/admin# cat /var/sadm/install/admin/custom
basedir=/opt/app/$PKGINST
root@host:/export/home/admin# pkgadd -a custom -d mysql-advanced-5.7.19-solaris11-sparc-64bit.pkg
...
Executing postinstall script.
ld.so.1: mysqld: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by file bin/mysqld)
ld.so.1: mysqld: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: open failed: No such file or directory
/var/sadm/pkg/mysql/install/postinstall: line 89: 7487: Killed
...
Installation of <mysql> was successful.
You have mail in /var/mail/root

# Change permission on /opt/app/mysql
root@host:/opt/app# chown -R mysql:mysql /opt/app/mysql

# Change to user: mysql
root@host:/opt/app# su - mysql

mysql@host:~$ cd /opt/app/mysql/mysql/bin
mysql@host:/opt/app/mysql/mysql/bin$ ./mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=/opt/app/mysql/mysql/data
ld.so.1: mysql_install_db: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by file mysql_install_db)
ld.so.1: mysql_install_db: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed
```

**Questions:**

1. What did I missed?
2. Did my step were correct?
3. Please advise how to correctly install mysql-advanced 5.7.19 to non default location (using tar preferably).

Comment: Check libstdc++6 is installed and try doing an update. I am not familiar with Solaris, so can't help further.

Comment: I checked that libstdc++6 is installed and updatedb command already performed.

Comment: First of all: this is not really a development question, so you may get better help over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/.  Secondly if you want non-default why didn't you simply download the tar, rather than the pkg, from the mysql.com site ?